# Swift: How use delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, searchbar

I have AllOrganizacionUIView class, I used UISearchBarDelegate delegate, on workink

```
class AllOrganizacionUIView: UIView , UISearchBarDelegate {

  @IBOutlet var SearchBar: UISearchBar!
  var searchActive : Bool = false

  func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true;
  }

  func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
  }

  func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
  }

  func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
    aa.SearchBar.endEditing(true)
    print("hajox")
  }
}
```

I Have use  UISearchBarDelegate delegate in ViewController class,

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController{
   @IBOutlet var SearchBar: UISearchBar!
   // not working
   func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
     self.CircleImageView_3.image = UIImage(named: "FullCircle")
     self.CircleImageView_2.image = UIImage(named: "Circle")
     self.CircleImageView_1.image = UIImage(named: "Circle")
     self.mMainCategory.hidden = true
     self.mAllCategores.hidden = true
     self.mAllOrganizations.hidden = false
     self.FooterViewController.text = "Основные категории"

     return true
   }
}
```

Help me please with this problem.

Comment: you should be more familiar with https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html
simply saying delegate is an object you keep reference to in your "searchBar" and by executing self.delegate.doSomething simply means you execute "doSomething" method in your object which you assigned delegate to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set delegate for your search bar, possibly in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.SearchBar.delegate = self
}
```

But it will be much better if you point the delegate on storyboard instead of code.

So, I see two problems in your code. First, you mean that your delegate is an `UIView` subclass. But then you mean that you want to use delegate which is implemented in `UIViewController` subclass.

You're able to have only one delegate at the same time. Choose one (view controller is preferred), and implement all delegate methods there. Then just set delegate as I said at the beginning of my answer.

Actually, I suggest you to read about [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW3) and delegates at the official Apple's documentation website. It is really necessary to read documentation carefully, because there are a lot of unique things in iOS that are different to another platforms.

Comment: if  use it  class AllOrganizacionUIView  UISearchDelegate not working

Comment: @ՍարգիսԽաչատրյան because you can have only one delegate at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
super.viewDidLoad()
self.SearchBar.delegate = self
```

}

or set your delegate in storyboard .